# i want to set cookie and get cookie from api in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js

i am trying to set cookies from  the server when the user login in nextjs, using the cookie library inside api/login/index.js using cookie.serialize is set the cookie but i cant get the from other route like api/users/index.js

here is my code: api/login/index.js
i dont no what am doing wrong

api/login/index.js and api/users/index.js

```
const adminModel = require("../../../model/admin.model");
// import env from "../../../config/env";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
var cookie = require("cookie");

export default function Login(req, res) {
  if (req.method.toUpperCase() == "POST") {
    //  console.log(process.env.DB_HOST," ",process.env.DB_USER,process.env.DB_PASSWORD," ",process.env.DB_NAME);
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (email && password) {
      var data = {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      };
      adminModel.getLogin(data, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(200).json({
            error: true,
            message: err,
          });
        } else {
          jwt.sign(
            { user: result[0] },
            process.env.JWT,
            { expiresIn: "1d" },
            (error, token) => {
              if (error) {
                res.send({
                  error: true,
                  message: error.message,
                });
              } else {
                const serialized = cookie.serialize(process.env.TOKEN, token, {
                  httpOnly: false,
                  secure: process.env.MODE_ENV !== "development",
                  sameSite: "strict",
                  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1, // 1 day
                  path: "/",
                });
                res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", serialized);
                res.status(200).send({
                  error: false,
                  message: "success",
                  // data: result,
                  token: token,
                });
              }
            }
          );
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({
        error: true,
        message: "Email and password can not be null",
      });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(200).json({
      error: true,
      message: "not a post method",
    });
  }
}


const userm = require("../../../model/user.mode");
var cookie = require("cookie");
export default function GetllUsers(req, res) {
  console.log(req.cookie);

  if (req.method.toUpperCase() == "GET") {
    userm.getUsers((err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(200).json({
          error: "true",
          message: err,
          users: [],
        });
      } else {
        res.status(200).json({
          error: "false",
          message: "success",
          users: result,
          cookie: req.cookies,
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({
      error: "true",
      message: "Only get Method are allowed",
      users: [],
    });
  }
}
```

i have tried a lot of doc like: cookiejs, cookies-cutter,and lot of doc on line and youtube but i cant get where my problem is coming from.

Comment: In my opinion the best option to work with Auth in Next is NextAuth.js. [link](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example)

Comment: thank i will try it